# ASP.NET Gridview - bootstrap 4 hide column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-4

This boundfield with visible parameter d-xl-block add unwanted border in column.
Any clear solution to the resolve it?

```
           <asp:BoundField DataField="casZaciatku" ItemStyle-CssClass="d-none d-xl-block  align-middle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="d-none d-xl-block  align-middle" HeaderText="CASZACIATKU_LNG" SortExpression="casZaciatku" meta:resourceKey="casZaciatk"></asp:BoundField>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found working solution. I add "d-sm-table-cell" into cssclass of gridview column with hiding property on small screen and "d-table-cell" to the all other.

Answer (score 0):

click inspect on the browser and  look at what class the border comes from. in css file find that class and edit as you wish